# Дублирование html таблицы

Tags: php, html

Вывожу данные из бд в таблицу по координатам (в свою ячейку), если записи с определенной координаты нет, то выводится X, проблема в том, что если в БД более 1 записи, то ИКСЫ дублируются, как я понимаю таблица должна перезаписываться, а не дополняться, как можно исправить?
Таблица сверху с 1 записью в бд, снизу с двумя, размер таблицы указывается пользователя

```
<?php
for ($tr=1; $tr<=$_SESSION['account']['rows']; $tr++){
  echo '<tr>';
    for ($td=1; $td<=$_SESSION['account']['columns']; $td++){
     foreach ($temp as $val) {
        echo '<td  class="tableEnd-item">';
           if ($tr == $val['x'] AND $td == $val['y']) {
              echo '<div><p>2</p> <span></span> <p class="tableLast-main__td__access">' .$val['chain0_temp']. '</p></td>';
           } else {
              echo '<div><p>x</p> <span></span> <p class="tableLast-main__td__access">x</p></td>';
           }
     }                                 
  }
              echo '</tr>';
 }                    
?>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

**Данные из бд:**

```
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["y"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["chain0_temp"]=>
    string(2) "69"
  }
   [1]=>
  array(3) {
    ["x"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["y"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["chain0_temp"]=>
    string(2) "69"
  }
 }
```

Comment: Покажите данные и отформатируйте код по человечески.

Comment: @nazarpunk, прошу прощения за код, обновил запись

Comment: `$tr == $val['x']` у вас `x` по вертикали?

Comment: @nazarpunk, Да, по вертикали

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если хотите перезаписывать таблицу, то используйте переменную.

```
for ($tr = 1; $tr <= $_SESSION['account']['rows']; $tr++) {
    echo '<tr>';
    for ($td = 1; $td <= $_SESSION['account']['columns']; $td++) {
        $value = '<div><p>x</p> <span></span> <p class="tableLast-main__td__access">x</p>';
        foreach ($temp as $val) {
            if ($tr == (int)$val['x'] and $td == (int)$val['y']) {
                $value = "<div><p>2</p> <span></span> <p class='tableLast-main__td__access'>{$val['chain0_temp']}</p>";
            }
        }
        echo "<td  class='tableEnd-item'>$value</td>";
    }
    echo '</tr>';
}
```

Comment: Благодаю, выучили